# Declare parameter into function scope

Tags: javascript

I'am trying to declare a parameter into an app constructor but it raise an exception..

```
var app = {

    // Where can i declare this param and how ?
    this.param1 : null,

    oneFunction: function() {
        // use param1 here..
    },

    secondFunction: function() {
        // use param1 here..
    }
}
```

How can i declare this param to use it into functions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `this`. The `param1` can be defined as a property of your object as below.

```
var app = {

    param1 : null,

    oneFunction: function() {
        // use param1 here..
    },

    secondFunction: function() {
        // use param1 here..
    }
}
```

Regarding the use of `param1` in your function, you can access it as `this.param1`. The `this` would refer to the `app` object.

For a plain example please have a look at the following snippet:

```js
var app = {

    param1 : null,

    oneFunction: function() {
        this.param1 = 4;
    },

    secondFunction: function() {
        console.log(this.param1);
    }
}

app.oneFunction();
app.secondFunction();
```

Comment: Given that `app` is a one-off, using `app.param1` might be more reliable (e.g., if `app.oneFunction` and such are used as callbacks).